# mod_rewrite: search for domain root in subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

On my website almost every single site is cached. A static htmfile is written from php to the folder:

> /__turbo_realcache/

If **mydomain.com/sitex.htm** is requested by a visitor, apache first looks if the file is found here:

```
/__turbo_realcache/sitex.htm
```

if the file is found it is delivered to the user. If the file does not exist in the cache-subfolder, the request is internally redirected to index.php (where the output is generated) and printed out via php.

This works well, but it doesnt work when the domain root is requested. So if a user calls

```
mydomain.com
```

What I'm seachring for is:
If a visitor is requesting **mydomain.com** in his browser then the htaccess should search for a static htmlfile called

> /__turbo_realcache/index.htm

If found, give it to the user (how to do this?). 
If not found, redirect to index.php (already working).

**This is my complete htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect www to non www
#############################################################################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# search for realcache static files. if found stop and be happy.
#############################################################################
RewriteCond         %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__turbo_realcache/%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__turbo_realcache/$1  [L]


# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
# Everything else goes to index.php where I decide what is shown to the user.
#############################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your *realcache static files* rules.

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__turbo_realcache/index.htm  -f
RewriteRule  ^  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__turbo_realcache/index.htm  [L]
```